# How do I get the value of clicked <span> from multiple spans inside multiple div's while using turn.js library

Tags: jquery, html, turn.js

How do I get the value of clicked  from multiple spans inside multiple div's. I have done this 
it works only if I don't apply the turn.js library other wise it doesn't work. the html I have

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="conversation">
    <div class="conversation-container  myconvo12">
      <div class="message received">
        <span class="name2">Imran Shah</span><br/><span id="18008"> net shta ? </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 12:35</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="message sent"> <span class="name">Atif</span><br><span id="18009"> Ao </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 12:35</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="message received">
        <span class="name2">Imran Shah</span><br><span id="18010"> ok </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 12:36</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="message received">
        <span class="name2">Imran Shah</span><br><span id="18028"> Halaka da kam ze ye ? </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 14:40</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'span', function ({
            var val = $(this).text()
          console.log(val)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
$('.message span').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).text()
  console.log(val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="conversation">
    <div class="conversation-container  myconvo12">
      <div class="message received">
        <span class="name2">Imran Shah</span><br/><span id="18008"> net shta ? </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 12:35</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="message sent"> <span class="name">Atif</span><br><span id="18009"> Ao </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 12:35</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="message received">
        <span class="name2">Imran Shah</span><br><span id="18010"> ok </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 12:36</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="message received">
        <span class="name2">Imran Shah</span><br><span id="18028"> Halaka da kam ze ye ? </span>
        <span class="metadata"><span class="time"> 14:40</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually this works if i don't apply the turn.js library but when i apply the turn.js then it it doesn't react to any click event I can't find any cdjns of that library and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upload this file

Comment: @ImranShah - there's an unwritten expectation in SO that we respect everyone's time by doing research, then when we can't solve the issue we post a question with a  [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue. So maybe do not post a big chunk of code and expect it to get a solution - the more specific and precise the question the more likely you will get a quick and clear answer.

Comment: @ImranShah since is not provided turn.js you can try jQuery instead of $ in case of any conflict with turn.js

Answer (score 0):

[Posting as an answer because a comment would not be clear / is too short]

There are issues with the sample code that you have posted and overall it is not clear where the bugs lie as there could be a few.

For example, in the code you posted as the click event listened, you refer to #msgid, which is not in your example html, and this.id looks like it should possibly be $(this).id but it is unclear in the context of your question, and also #msg is not present in your example and I can't understand why you would want to refer to event.taret there.

```
$(document).on('click', 'span', function ({
            $('#msgid').val(this.id);
            $('#msg').val($(event.target).
        });
```

I recommend that you review and edit your question and make it more obvious what you are trying to do and what issues you are experiencing.

Comment: sorry for that msgid as i was in a hurry so couldn't focus on that . I actually need the clicked span value. Now this code of your's works if i don't apply the turn.js library but when i apply the turn.js then it it doesn't react to any click event I can't find any cdjns of that library on the internet and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upload this file if you want i can send the code to you there u can debug it easily